Is there a way in C# to get all the third party packages/libraries (source code not binary) being used in the project
Like in Golang,Python and Java, we can easily get all the third party packages being used in the projects using their package managers.
example :
go mod vendor in Golang and mvn dependency:copy-dependencies in Java etc

I am trying to find any utility from nuget/dotnet package manager which does the same.
dotnet list <project solution> 

will fetch only the names of the third party packages but I need source code of those third party packages.
any help on this please.
dotnet list <path to the project solution file> 

Above command just lists the third party packages but I need to get the source code of those libraries.

"Above command just lists the third party packages but I need to get the source code of those libraries." - I don't think you do but granted you would: What makes you think all of the sources are even available? There might be closed-source dependencies.

I need them because we need to identify all the third party libraries being used in our project and send them to blackduck team which does some sort of scans over these libraries to find if there are any vulnerabilities, outdated licensed etc.
since I am totally new to c#, I thought we have something similar to golang and java to download third party libraries using their package manager tool.

currently, I am going over each and every third party which is listed and downloading them via web interface which is very tedious task and time consuming.

I figure, yes. And will become exponentially more tedious with your project growing. Now, the thing with C# / NuGet is that it's different from for example the go package management. Available sources aren't mandatory. And on top of that: You don't necessarily have to use nuget. Your project could directly reference some DLL, not even to start with p/invoke...

But maybe this article can ease your pain a little: How to Scan NuGet Packages for Security Vulnerabilities

To me this sounds like Blackduck are offloading what could be expected to be part of their job to you. Similar tools like Grype seem to have a less laborious approach.

@DayanandaDR the only reason you can get the packages in other languages is because they're saved in a manifest locally. In .NET Core (which includes .NET 5 and later) the detailed dependencies are stored in obj/project.assets.json.

As for vulnerabilities, that's built into NuGet nowadays, with annoying alerts popping up in Visual Studio if you use a package with a known vulnerability. From the command line you can use dotnet list package –vulnerable for direct dependencies or dotnet list package –vulnerable –include-transitive for all dependencies

From the comments it seems the real question is whether there are known vulnerabilities for a .NET project's dependencies. In .NET Core (which includes .NET 5 and later) dependencies come either as NuGet packages or references to your own projects. Binaries are no longer just copied to the Global Assembly Cache. You can just copy a binary and load it, but that requires a lot of extra work.
NuGet started reporting packages with vulnerabilities in 2023. These vulnerabilities appear as hard-to-miss notifications in Visual Studio (which is how I found out about them).

You can also list vulnerabilities from the command line  with dotnet list --vulnerable. The --include-transitive flag shows indirect dependencies as well
 dotnet list package --include-transitive --vulnerable

The following sources were used:
   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\

Project `xxxx` has the following vulnerable packages
   [net8.0]:
   Transitive Package               Resolved   Severity   Advisory URL
   > Azure.Identity                 1.10.3     Moderate   https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wvxc-855f-jvrv
   > Microsoft.Identity.Client      4.56.0     Low        https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-x674-v45j-fwxw

Allow me to %$!&%&!@#$&*@!#$ because I don't use Azure, the vulnerable packages are indirect dependencies of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
Listing dependencies
In your projects or solutions you can list all direct dependencies with
dotnet list

Project 'xxxx' has the following package references
   [net8.0]:
   Top-level Package                      Requested             Resolved
   > AutoMapper                           13.0.1                13.0.1
   > CsvHelper                            31.0.0                31.0.0
   > Dapper                               2.1.28                2.1.28
   > Dapper.Contrib                       2.0.78                2.0.78
   > FastMember                           1.5.0                 1.5.0
   > Microsoft.Data.SqlClient             5.1.5                 5.1.5
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting         8.0.0                 8.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging         8.0.0                 8.0.0
   > Serilog.Extensions.Hosting           8.0.0                 8.0.0
   > Serilog.Extensions.Logging           8.0.0                 8.0.0
   > Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File      3.0.0                 3.0.0
   > Serilog.Sinks.Console                5.0.1                 5.0.1
   > Serilog.Sinks.File                   5.0.0                 5.0.0
   > Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer            6.5.2                 6.5.2
   > System.CommandLine.Hosting           0.4.0-alpha.22272.1   0.4.0-alpha.22272.1

You can get indirect dependencies as well with the --include-transitive switch.
dotnet list --include-transitive 

Project 'xxx' has the following package references
   [net8.0]:
   Top-level Package                      Requested             Resolved
   > AutoMapper                           13.0.1                13.0.1
   > CsvHelper                            31.0.0                31.0.0
   > Dapper                               2.1.28                2.1.28
   > Dapper.Contrib                       2.0.78                2.0.78
   > FastMember                           1.5.0                 1.5.0
   > Microsoft.Data.SqlClient             5.1.5                 5.1.5
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting         8.0.0                 8.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging         8.0.0                 8.0.0
   > Serilog.Extensions.Hosting           8.0.0                 8.0.0
   > Serilog.Extensions.Logging           8.0.0                 8.0.0
   > Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File      3.0.0                 3.0.0
   > Serilog.Sinks.Console                5.0.1                 5.0.1
   > Serilog.Sinks.File                   5.0.0                 5.0.0
   > Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer            6.5.2                 6.5.2
   > System.CommandLine.Hosting           0.4.0-alpha.22272.1   0.4.0-alpha.22272.1

   Transitive Package                                                                   Resolved
   > Antlr4.Runtime.Standard                                                            4.13.1
   > Antlr4BuildTasks                                                                   12.8.0
   > Azure.Core                                                                         1.35.0
   > Azure.Identity                                                                     1.10.3
   > EPPlus                                                                             7.0.9
   > EPPlus.Interfaces                                                                  6.1.1
   > EPPlus.System.Drawing                                                              6.1.1
   > FParsec                                                                            1.1.1
   > FSharp.Core                                                                        8.0.200
...

Adding --vulnerable shows the vulnerabilities for the dependencies, either direct or transient.
You can also list outdated packages with the --outdated switch :
dotnet list package --outdated

The following sources were used:
   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\

Project `xxx` has the following updates to its packages
   [net8.0]:
   Top-level Package                 Requested             Resolved              Latest
   > CsvHelper                       31.0.0                31.0.0                32.0.3
   > Dapper                          2.1.28                2.1.28                2.1.35
   > Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer       6.5.2                 6.5.2                 6.6.0

